# How do I load the 64-bit Visual Studio Tools Command Prompt?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, 64-bit

My development machine is running Windows 7 Ultimate x64. I installed Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. When I open the **Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)**, I get the message

> Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.

I have also setup the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/) in my Windows PowerShell user profile. And I use the `Invoke-BatchFile` cmdlet to install the Visual Studio Tools into all my PowerShell sessions

```
$vcargs = ?: {$Pscx:Is64BitProcess} {'amd64'} {'x86'}
$vcvars = "${env:VS100COMNTOOLS}..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
Invoke-BatchFile $vcvars $vcargs
```

My `vcargs` resolves to `amd64`. I looked in the `vcvarsall.bat` file for the location of the x64 batch file and got `~dp0bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat`. That directory (and file) does not exist.

How do I get the `vcvars64.bat` file installed properly?

Comment: I have tried installing both the Windows 7 and .NET 3.5 SP1 SDK and the Windows 7 and .NET 4.0 SDK. They installed the `~dp0bin\amd64\` directory, but not the x64 batch file.

Comment: I only installed the C# development environment (when I installed VS2010).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Install the x64 Components

The problem is an incomplete installation of Visual Studio. I only installed the C# components. I needed to install, at least, the **Visual C++ x64 Compilers and Tools**.

### Adding Components to an Existing Installation

I had [problems](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/557841/error-while-adding-features-to-an-existing-installation) adding those components to an existing installation. VS2010, especially with SP1 installed, has a ton of bugs around modifying the installation. I encountered some kind of path not found error

1. I uninstalled SP1 first. I *needed* the VS2010 installation media on hand ([unpack](http://www.7-zip.org/) to a directory, insert the real disc, or [mount](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html) to a virtual drive).
2. Then I added the VC++ components to the VS installation
3. Then I was able to reinstall SP1.

Comment: Don't uninstall anything, this is a known bug with a simple workaround.

Comment: Connect bug submitted https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/648412/

Comment: Man, downvote without a comment sucks. Is it about the disagreement with Hans? I don't know how to state my case any differently. I did not have the components Hans was referring to without installing the VC++ x64 tools.

Answer (score 5):

When running in the batch processor, %~dp0 expands to the path where the .bat file is executing.  So in the default install for VS2010, that resolves to c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat.  Which is indeed missing, that's a bug they don't seem to be [interesting in fixing](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/510784/vcvarsall-bat-amd64-environment-is-missing).

Use "x86_amd64" instead.  You'll get the cross compiler, the same one that's used by the IDE.

Comment: I looked at the path for that parameter, `%~dp0bin\x86_amd64\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat`. That file also doesn't exist on my machine.

Comment: Did you get the explanation of what %~dp0 means?  This .bat file *does* exist (vc\bin\x86_amd64 subdirectory), unless you intentionally skipped installing the 64-bit compilers.  Test by typing "vcvarsall x86_amd64" at the command line prompt.

Comment: I know what ~dp0 is. I'm running `vcvarsall.bat` which you provide an architecture switch (I'm passing in `amd64`). That bat file points you to the bat file for your architecture. None of the x64 specific bat files exist on my machine.

Comment: You have the vc\bin\x86_amd64 directory but it doesn't contain the vcvarsx86_amd64.bat file?  Dated 11/15/2009?  Rough, start by running Repair.

Comment: `(I'm passing in amd64)`.  That was the point of my answer.  Don't.  Pass in x86_amd64.

Comment: Haha, yeah, did that already. I'm really certain that it's because I didn't install the VC++ components at first. But now I'm paying the uninstall/re-install costs (time time time). These installation bugs are killing me.

Comment: The only param that resolves to a good bat file is `x86`. But I'm on an x64 machine. I should be able to use the x64 tools. I want to use the x64 tools. I'm going to fight this fight until I win!

Comment: the only bat file I have is vcvars32.bat - but cl.exe exists in the relevant subdirs. How do I get vcvars64.bat?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into roughly the same problem a number of times. It appears that the structure MS has set up for this is so fragile that installing or removing any software on the same machine (or, apparently, breathing anywhere near that machine) can and will break it. Worse, they have a nearly impenetrable web of batch files invoking each other, that in the end carry out some fairly trivial tasks in what appears to be nearly the most roundabout way possible.

Although I suppose it wastes a bit of memory I decided to simplify my life a bit, and use this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <process.h>

void setenv(std::string const &name, std::string const &value) { 
    SetEnvironmentVariable(name.c_str(), value.c_str());
}

std::string vs_base = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\";
std::string vc_base = vs_base + "VC\\";
std::string sdk_dir = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\";

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    char inc_name[] = "INCLUDE";
    char lib_name[] = "LIB";
    char path_name[] = "PATH";

    std::string inc_dir = getenv(inc_name);
    std::string lib_dir = getenv(lib_name);
    std::string path_dir = getenv(path_name);

    inc_dir = vc_base + "include;" + sdk_dir + "include;" + inc_dir;
    lib_dir = vc_base + "lib;" + sdk_dir + "lib;" + lib_dir;
    path_dir = vc_base + "bin;" + sdk_dir + "bin;" + vs_base + "Common7\\IDE;" + path_dir;

    setenv(inc_name, inc_dir);
    setenv(lib_name, lib_dir);
    setenv(path_name, path_dir);

    char path[MAX_PATH];

    GetSystemDirectory(path, sizeof(path));
    strcat(path, "\\cmd.exe");
    _spawnlp(_P_WAIT, path, path, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

You'll have to adjust the base directories at the top for the locations where you have things installed. One of these days I suppose I should rewrite this to use a separate configuration file (I've pretty much worked out an XML format that should work reasonably well), but this has worked well enough that I haven't bothered to finish that, and since it's for a programmer anyway, doing a trivial modification and re-compile isn't particularly onerous.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem, where I had visual studio 2010 professional (i'm guessing not SP1, it says "Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel" in About), and I also had the problem where in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC` folder, it had vcvarsall.bat, but all of the paths that it tried to find any of the other .bat files were invalid, aka I had no other bat files.

I came across [this forum post](http://www.w7forums.com/threads/vcvarsall-bat-no-64bit-support-vcvars64-bat-missing.6606/) and it was the only thing that solved my problem.
Some people here were also saying "just use SetEnv" but i didn't know where it was because it wasn't in my PATH (typing setenv resulted in 'command not found'), so this is a more complete answer, that i'm posting here so people don't have to struggle like I did for so long

Posting here for archival purposes:

> The batch file to set the environment parameters to compile for 64 bit
>   is contained in the Windows SDK.
>
> After installing the Windows SDK use the following call CALL
>   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.cmd" /x64
>
> Or create file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\vc\bin\amd64\vcvars64bat with the line above.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1?

Open your ordinary Visual Studio Command Prompt and type:

```
setenv /x64
```

If your 64bit compilers are missing, you might need to read [KB2519277](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2519277).